# Why don't list objects belong to a class?

Tags: python

From the [classes tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html):

> In Python, the term method is not
>   unique to class instances: other
>   object types can have methods as well.
>   For example, list objects have methods
>   called append, insert, remove, sort,
>   and so on.

One implication I can find is this gives an error: `[].foo = 'bar'`. Are there other implications? Why isn't list implemented as a class? Is this because of historic reasons?

Comment: Lists, and everything else, *are* instances of a class. Not a class written in Python, but still a class. The wording in the tutorial is... unfortunate.

Comment: Why do you call that an _"implication"_ ?? I don't see the 'cause to effect' relation that would make the "error" a consequence of.... of what , by the way ? And why should a list be a class ??! A list is an instance of type 'list" , not a class in itself. What do you mean, in fact ? Your question has little sense to me.

Comment: @eyquem - in most programming languages I know, basic data structures such as lists and dictionaries are normal classes, not privileged "types". I'm trying to grock what's the difference between types and classes in Python, and why lists aren't classes.

Comment: See my full answer please. I repeat : _" why should a list be a class ??!"_ Are you sure that in other languages , LISTS are CLASSES ? In Python, a list is an instance of a type (that is to say a class) whose name is `<type 'list'>`

Answer (score 2):

lists are implemented as a class:

```
>>> [].__class__
<type 'list'>
```

It's just you can't assign to arbitrary attributes on them. The same applies to other types e.g. strings.

```
>>> "foo".bar = "something"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Comment: Python types are not classes, they are objects. Both Python types and classes are instances of objects.

Comment: @Y.H.Wong What is an object , according to you ?

Answer (score 2):

Some people might give you a better explanation but I think this is the basics.

There was a [time](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) (pre Python 2.2.3) where [user defined] classes and types aren't really the same. Python has always had basic built-in types like `int`s, `float`s, `list`s, `tuple`s, `dict`s and etc. When you call `type([])`, you get a `type` back, but not a `class`. Python built-in types don't allow their objects to have attributes other then their inherited ones attached. But check this new-style class out in Python version > 2.3:

```
>>> class C(object):
>>>     pass

>>> type(C())
<class '__main__.C'>

>>> type([])
<type 'list'>
```

I think this is what the tutorial means in by "the term method is not unique to class instances: other object types can have methods as well".

For a detailed explanation of how `type`s and `object`s are unified now, check [this](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html) link out.

Answer (score 0):

list objects actually *IS* belongs(or is instance of) builtin type/class 'list'

for example:

```
>>> list1 = []
>>> print type(list1)
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the builtin types (list, str, tuple, dict) *are* classes (and instances of them objects) but to help with run-time efficiency, they aren't as flexible as classes you might write in pure Python. The language implementation trades off the ability to set arbitrary attributes on (for example) list objects for overall faster performance.

Answer (score 0):

Despite of being a python newb, I'll try to answer this myself. I got some great answers here, but none of them explains **why** don't list objects belong to a class.

I assume there isn't a "good" reason, it's just legacy. They were originally implemented before Python had classes, and weren't retrofitted (yet).